# rotation matrix in openCV

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, transformation, scikit-image

I am creating a rotation matrix in python as follows:

```
import numpy as np
def make_rot(angle):
    cost = np.cos(np.deg2rad(angle))
    sint = np.sin(np.deg2rad(angle))
    rot = np.array([[cost, -sint, 0],
                   [sint, cost, 0],
                   [0, 0, 1]])
    return rot
```

This is as defined in the wikipedia page here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix

I run it with the angle parameter as 45 degrees and I get something like:

```
[[ 0.70710678 -0.70710678  0.        ]
 [ 0.70710678  0.70710678  0.        ]
 [ 0.          0.          1.        ]]
```

Now, I use the OpenCV `getRotationMatrix2D` API as follows:

```
import cv2
M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D((0, 0), 45, 1)
```

The matrix I get is the inverse of the matrix (the transpose as it is a rotation matrix). The result is as follows:

```
[[ 0.70710678  0.70710678  0.        ]
 [-0.70710678  0.70710678  0.        ]]
```

As you can see it is the inverse. I have not found anything in the OpenCV documentation which says anything about this behaviour.

Now, I can use this matrix in OpenCV and `skimage` to transform an image as follows:

```
# openCV
M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D((0, 0), 45, 1)
dst = cv2.warpAffine(image2, M, (coumns, rows))

# skimage
from skimage import transform as tf
tform = tf.AffineTransform(matrix=make_rot(45))
dst = tf.warp(image_2, tform)
```

The surprising thing is that the result from using my matrix and OpenCV matrix is the same.

My question is why is OpenCV working with the inverse of the transformation? I am wondering if this is something they are not mentioning in the documentation or if I am using this wrong somehow.

Comment: Should depend on whether it rotates clockwise or counter-clockwise... openCV doc says it uses [cos sin; -sin cos] for ccw rotation but Im not sure whether that is right. Just try whether it is cw or ccw  by warping or multiplying points; )

Comment: Mind this part of wikipedia: "The examples in this article apply to active rotations of vectors counter-clockwise in a right-handed coordinate system by pre-multiplication. If any one of these is changed (e.g. rotating axes instead of vectors, i.e. a passive transformation), then the inverse of the example matrix should be used, which coincides precisely with its transpose." So maybe image origin (top left or bottom left e.g.) differ in sci-kit and openCV?

Comment: This must be it. I will investigate.

Comment: So it turns out that skimage warp function expects the inverse transform (from the output image to the input image). I am not sure why that is. This is not a problem for affine transformations as they are bijective. However, having the transformation used from input coordinates->output coordinates is better imo.

Comment: To prevent leaving holes in the output image, the inverse transformation should be a better choice.

Comment: Inverse is normally used for warping to get a value for each discrete pixel of the destination image as lanpa already said. openCV will compute the inverse during warping if you dont set the WARP_INVERSE_MAP flag. If you set WARP_INVERSE_MAP flag then it assumes you provide the inverse already.

Comment: You can use `skimage.transform.SimilarityTransform(angle=X)`, or simply use `skimage.transform.rotate(angle=X, resize=False)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the problem is that in a traditional right-handed coordinate system the rotation matrix looks exactly like the one you are using.

Whereas in images (and `OpenCV` works with images) the origin is in the top-left corner, the x-axis goes to the right (as usual), but y-axis goes down rather than up, which means that the coordinate system is left-handed and the rotation matrix is different.

Let's build the rotation matrix in this coordinate system. If we denote:

`A` - linear transformation (rotation in our case)

then we get

`A(i) = (cos(angle), -sin(angle))`

where `i` - is the base vector corresponding to x-axis

`A(j) = (sin(angle), cos(angle))`

where `j`- is the base vector for y-axis.

Consequently, rotation matrix looks exactly like in `OpenCV`:

`A(i)` is its first column,

`A(j)` is the second one.

Comment: Is this behavior documented somewhere?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I have no idea whether this is documented anywhere or not. To me, it is just common sense and understanding of what a classical rotation matrix is. It really worked for me: I needed the rotation matrix to cut out a slightly rotated square from an image and then to recalculate the coordinates of the cell inside this square.

Comment: @Him the behaviour in question is simply "x is to the right, and y is down, (not up)", which differs from mathematical convention in that it mirors everything, affecting rotation. Rather than adjusting the rotation matrix, I prefer to follow a convention where 'positive rotation' means 'from x towards y' (as in standard convention) and then the roate matrix looks like the standard one, but the rotations sign changes: CW is positive for the left-handed axes. Unfortunately  `getRotationMatrix2D` does not follow this and uses CCW = postiive.